# How to get all the loaded bundles in Equinox 3.10 and onwards

Tags: osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

I want to programmatically retrieve all the bundles that are loaded. In an older version we were using it in this fashion:

```
    Field osgiField = EclipseStarter.class.getDeclaredField("osgi"); 
    osgiField.setAccessible(true);
    final org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi osgi =
          (org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi) osgiField.get(null);
    osgi.getBundleContext().getBundles();
```

How to retrieve all the loaded bundles in the latest osgi?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from outside OSGi or from a bundle?

Comment: I'm trying to do this from another bundle

Comment: What you really seem to need is to get hold of the OSGi BundleContext, and previously you were using a *very* strange hack to get hold of it. The proper way to do this is to implement a Bundle Activator.

Answer (score 2):

From a  bundle you can either implement the BundleActivator interface and mark your class in the Manifest as "BundleActivator:my.ClassName".

Or if that is not possible you can use FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext().

Also see this question: [Best technique for getting the OSGi bundle context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527306/best-technique-for-getting-the-osgi-bundle-context)

Then use bundleContext.getBundles();

These approaches should work with any OSGi framework.